# MySQL syntax to not select '_' data in the column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am glad if any one could help me out here.

I have a table Table1 and column XXXXXX with the data as following

```
XXXXXX
---------
1
2
1
2
x_y
A_12
3
12345_abcd
```

I want the output as

```
XXXXXX
---------
1
2
3
```

I have tried the following query

```
select DISTINCT XXXXXX from Table1 where XXXXXX NOT LIKE '%_%';
```

Also tried `SELECT DISTINCT XXXXXX FROM Table1 WHERE CHAR ('_','XXXXXX')=0;`

The above query is fetching everything from the table. Can anyone help me on this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
WHERE  XXXXXX NOT LIKE '%\\_%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

The "escape" character is what tells MySQL that the underscore is to be interpreted as literal underscore character, and not a wildcard. (In the LIKE expression, an underscore (`_`) is a wildcard that matches any single character, just as the percent (`%`) is a wildcard that matches zero, one or more characters.

Note that other characters can be used as the escape character; it doesn't have to be the backslash. The backslash is itself an escape character in MySQL, so have a backslash recognized as the escape character for the LIKE, we have to use double backslashes "`\\`". That makes MySQL recognize this as a single backslash character.

As an example, we can use the carat "`^`" character as the escape character, like this:

```
WHERE  XXXXXX NOT LIKE '%^_%' ESCAPE '^'
```

Similarly, the escape character can be used to search for a literal percent sign `%` using a LIKE operator like this:

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%\\%%' ESCAPE '\\'
```

(That will search for an occurrence of a percent sign character in foo.)

---

As an alternative to the NOT LIKE operator, we can use the 'NOT REGEXP' operator to exclude rows where foo contains an underscore character, like this:

```
WHERE foo NOT REGEXP '_'
```

Comment: Gr8 so thankful for your tuting. Information was valuable and appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   select XXXXXX from Table1 
   where XXXXXX NOT LIKE '%_%'
   GROUP BY XXXXXX
```

**EDIT** .

TRY THIS

```
   select XXXXXX from Table1 
   where  XXXXXX NOT LIKE '%\\_%' ESCAPE '\\'
   GROUP BY XXXXXX
```

[**DEMO HERE SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/332b8/2)

Comment: :This query doesnt fetch any data. Returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Distinct coolColumnName 
from CoolTableName
WHERE coolColumnName not like '%_%'
```

Comment: I have done that query if you see my question. It is fetching 0 rows. showing simply no data.